# Search a file that was created

Tags: c#

When I create the file and append to it the rest of the information I now want to have the ability to read the text file then display the Month of a birthday thats listed in the file.
I want to be able to pull in just the info by birthday. So if I choose month 11 I want to pull in all the data entries that have a birthmonth of 11 by pushing button4.

This is what I have so far;

```
 private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        writetext();
        reset();

    }
    public void writetext()
    {

        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("filename.txt"))

        {
         writer.WriteLine("First name, {0} Lastname, {1} Phone,{2} Day of birth,{3} Month of Birth{4}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, maskedTextBox1.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text);
         MessageBox.Show(String.Format("First Name,{0} Lastname, {1} Phone,{2} Day of birth,{3} Month of Birth{4}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, maskedTextBox1.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text)); 
        }
        }
    public void reset()
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        maskedTextBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(); 
     }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {
        readfile(); 


    }

    private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void readfile()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
        label6.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
    }
}






 }
```

Comment: How do I just pull in the data by month when I push button4.

Comment: So if I choose month 11 I want to pull in all the data entries that have a birthmonth of 11 by pushing button4 and display it in label7.

Comment: Why did the question get a negative 1

Comment: I would guess that the question is unclear. Personally, I don't quite understand what you want. Might I suggest reading your question from the viewpoint of someone who knows nothing about your problem and seeing if it is understandable - then add clarification where you see fit.

Comment: Post a sample file output, that will help people understand how you want to select data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as Geoffrey but with C# and linq syntax:

You can filter the content of your file using the birth date and store it in a new array this way:

```
string[] persons = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("filename.txt"));
IEnumerable<string> personsWithBirthday =
  from p in persons
    where p.Contains("1980-08-21")
      select p;
foreach (var person in personsWithBirthday)
 Response.Write(person);
```

I would recommend you to define a standard date format in order to easily grab all the persons matching the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me for using vb.net syntax here as I am more acustomed to it. The translation should be quite straightforward though:

```
Dim rdr As New IO.StreamReader("filename.txt")
While rdr.Peek <> -1
   Dim strLine as String = rdr.ReadLine()
   If strLine.Contains("Birth Month,11") Then
      Label6.Text &= strLine
   End If
End While
rdr.Close()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That works for November, but it won't work for January (would also match October, November, and December).

Comment: obviously you can parametrisize it by using "Birth Month," & intMonth instead

Comment: On another note I prefer this line by line approach to the ReadAllLines method. It is a good way to go with potentially very large files since it does not require storage of the entire file in memory.